# Apache Camel XML-to-JSON

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I have simple XML file and need to convert it to JSON using `camel-xmljson` JAR. I have started camel context using:

```
Main main = new Main();
main.addRouteBuilder(new ConvertXmlToJson());
main.enableHangupSupport();
main.run();
```

And my configure method looks like:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
    xmlJsonFormat.setForceTopLevelObject(true);

    // from XML to JSON

    //#1
    from("direct:marshal").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("mock:json"); 

    //#2
    //from("file:resources/SimpleFile.xml").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("file:resources/JsonOutput.txt");
}
```

Now I am not able to understand where should I exactly pass my xml object? Is #2 looks correct? Nothing happens when I execute any one of them.

It will be fine as well to print converted JSON on the console rather than file.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you sure your are sending an XML to `direct:marshal` or you have a file in `resources`? Should it be `src/main/resources`?

Comment: @hveiga My 'resources' directory exists directly under project folder. I am able to get hold of file when I perform -- File xmlDocumentFile = new File("resources/SampleFile.xml");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your route to:

```
from("file:resource/inbox").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("file:resource/outbox");
```

Then copy SimpleFile.xml into resource/inbox, run the application and you will get JSON in resource/outbox

Comment: Thanks, how will it work if there are 2 XML files in resource/inbox folder? Can we provide specific XML file as input?

Comment: if you have 2 XML files in resource/inbox, you will get 2 JSON files in resource/outbox. What is the point to specify XML file as input?

Comment: I want to provide one big XML as input and need output in JSON format.

Comment: This does not work, my code looks like: from("file:C:/inbox").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("file:C:/outbox"); -- where I put XML file inside 'inbox' folder.

Comment: No error, it just pass through without generating JSON output.

Comment: Camel did not threw any exception and hence I was not able to determine the issue. Later on when I add **ezmorph-1.0.4.jar** file, everything started working. I will accept @Sergey's answer. Thanks for all the help.